# Insert a variable into url string - Django App

Tags: javascript, python, django, url

I am developing a Django App and I need to insert a variable into a url string defined in the front-end (javascript) to get a json file from a user's folder:

```
'{% static "users/ userName /file.json" %}'
```

I would like to have `userName` as a variable. I need this url for jstree plugin. I have to display the user's folder tree:

```
 userFolder = '{% static "users/userName/file.json" %}'

 $('#jstree').jstree({
   "core" : {
   "animation" : 0,
   "check_callback" : true,
   "themes" : { "stripes" : true },
   'data' : {
   "url" : userFolder,

      ... more code ...
   })
```

I tried different syntaxes but no luck so far. Do you know any solution for this?

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score -1):

There are three possible methods of string concatenation mentioned in [jsperf comparison](https://jsperf.com/concat-vs-plus-vs-join):

- **Best way performance wise** (*and apparently easiest to understand*) of    concatenating strings is by using [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) (`+`, `+=`) operators:

  ```
  '{% static "users/' + userName + '/file.json" %}'
  ```
- **Second best option** (*at least in newer browsers*) is concatenating with [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) function:

  > The **`concat()`** method combines the text of one or more strings and returns a new string.

  Solution using this method would look like this:

  ```
  ''.concat(['{% static "users/', userName, '/file.json" %}'])
  ```
- **Third option** would include using [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function:

  > The **`join()`** method joins all elements of an array (or an array-like object) into a string and returns this string.

  String formatting with using this method would look like this:

  ```
  ['{% static "users/', userName, '/file.json" %}]'.join()
  ```

  *please note, that this time concatenation is performed from array of strings instead of strings.*

For example if you would `userName` should be equal to `'FooBar'`, then output would be

```
'{% static "users/JonDoe/file.json" %}'
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I still get an error: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal.

Comment: I guess, there should be double quotes in the middle. "users/"+userName+"/file.json"

Comment: @Sim81 which version of python do you use? Also I updated answer.

Comment: @Sim81 all of my mentioned methods worked fine in both Python 3 and Python 2. Perhaps you should describe your problem more specifically? In what context are you trying to use your string? What output are you expecting? Try updating your description.

Comment: @Lycopersicum I am using  Python 2.7.12.  I tried all of them but I still get errors! With the first and third syntax I get:
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal.
With the second syntaxI get: Could not parse the remainder. 
 thank you for your help!

Comment: @Sim81 could you update your question with libraries and lines of code included? I could test it myself.

Comment: @Lycopersicum I added some extra code. I need the url for a jstree plugin. Thank you!

Comment: @Sim81 I will try to Improve my answer in few hours, currently I cannot use python pip because of insufficient rules.

Comment: @Lycopersicum Thank you for your help I really I appreciate !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161280/discussion-between-lycopersicum-and-sim81).

Comment: @Lycopersicum Sorry for the late reply, but I manged to solve the problem following your guide lines. Thank you very much for your help !!!

Comment: @Sim81 Thanks for response! Comment section is dedicated for questions and clarifying things. If answer is correct, you should accept it, so others seeking for help could find relevant answers. There's [guide on what to do when somebody answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).